# Embedding Images into Email - What is the difference between ContentID and ContentLocation?

Tags: asp.net, email, mime

I am using aspNetEmail to send emails with embedded images and I am trying to choose between two options:

**ContentLocation:**   Embed images using the Content-Location header.
**ContentId:**         Embed images using the Content-ID header.

I checked the aspNetEmail website for documentation but there wasn't very much information.  I suspect these options are applicable to embedding images in all email applications?

What is the difference between the two settings, and how will it affect my emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ContentId**

Represents an identifier to the contents of the attachment. ContentId can be set to any string value. Applications can use ContentId to implement their own identification mechanisms.

**ContentLocation**

Contains the Uniform Resource Identifier (URI) that corresponds to the location of the content of the attachment.

Comment: Cool - You answered your own question a few months later.. Im sure somebody will find it usefull :)